# How to Backfill Individual Features within a Group with SageMaker Feature Store

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker, aws-feature-store

I'm evaluating SageMaker feature store but am finding that custom backfilling doesn't appear to be straight forward. I need to be able to backfill new features that are added to feature groups. If I add a new feature to a feature group I will have an incomplete table for that feature.

| record id | event time | old feature | new feature | write time | is deleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | timestamp | data | nan | timestamp | false |
| 1 | timestamp | data | nan | timestamp | false |
| 2 | timestamp | data | data | timestamp | false |

My first though was to delete the incomplete records and then insert the new backfilled record. But if I delete the record id 0 or 1 from the offline store it will insert a gravestone record to show delete time rather than hard delete the original row.

| record id | event time | old feature | new feature | write time | is deleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | timestamp | data | nan | timestamp | false |
| 1 | timestamp | data | nan | timestamp | false |
| 2 | timestamp | data | data | timestamp | false |
| 0 | timestamp |  |  | timestamp | true |
| 1 | timestamp |  |  | timestamp | true |

How can I backfill individual features?